# Simple Android SQLite Database Inserstion code

Tags: android, sqlite

found Error in creating simple SQLite databas Android Application

```
**03-12 12:57:39.635: E/Database(333): Failure 1 
(near "tablefriends": syntax error) on 0x29b2b0 
when preparing 'create tablefriends(_id integer 
primary key autoincrement,name text not null,address text);
```

when i write this code in my activity class, my application even did not run. but if i removed this code from activity class , my application run but it gives exception when i insert data into the database

```
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    FriendsDataSource s=new FriendsDataSource(this);
    s.closedatabase();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    FriendsDataSource s=new FriendsDataSource(this);
    s.opendatabase();
}

public static final String FRIENDS_TABLE_CREATE_STMT="create table"+TABLE_NAME+
       "("+COLUMN_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+
       COLUMN_FRIEND_NAME+" text not null,"+COLUMN_ADDRESS+" text);";
```

Comment: I'd like to add that you should rather create an object-scope instance of `FriendsDataSource` in `onResume` and close the database of that instance instead of creating two instances, like `mFriendsSource = new FriendsDataSource(this);` where `mFriendsSource` is a member of the class.

Answer (score 2):

You've got problems with your spacing as so often happens when concatenating strings;

```
"create table" + TABLE_NAME // becomes "create tablefriends"
```

When ending up with strange SQL errors, it's always a good idea to look at/trace the generated string so that it matches what you expect. In this case, your error message right at the top of the question shows the error though.

The correct version should be;

```
"create table " + TABLE_NAME // becomes "create table friends"
```

Comment: it still gives me an exception when i press button of "add friend"

Comment: @ZaidIqbal You're not showing any code or the exception for "Add friend" in this question, you may want to start a new question with all info you have on that.

Comment: 03-12 16:56:25.652: E/Database(334): Failure 1 (near "tablefriends": syntax error) on 0x29b268 when preparing 'create tablefriends(_id integer primary key autoincrement,name text not null,address text);'.

Comment: i have debug the code and found exception in this line "long id=friendsDB.insert(FriendsMetaData.TABLE_NAME, null, newFriendValues);  "